# Drawing a 2D non-local random walk

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]

I need help with this drawing. I somehow have a slight idea on how to do it, but I was unable to do it.

I need to draw a non-local random walk (just like the image).
The draw itselft its really simple: a $x$ in the middle, a $x + vector*h$ in each corner. Also with an arrow pointing each corner with an interrogation symbol above (or below) it

The code I used for the local random walk

```
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0) ; 
            \foreach \x/\y in  {-3/{$x-e_{1}h$},3/{$x+e_{1}h$}}  
            \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};

        \node[below right] at (3pt,-3pt) {$x$};
        
        \draw (0,-3)`enter code here` -- (0,3) ; 
        \foreach \x/\y in  {-3/{$x-e_{2}h$},3/{$x+e_{2}h$}}  
        \draw[shift={(0,\x)},color=black] (-3pt,0pt) -- (3pt,0pt)node[right] {\y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: --not a complete answer but something to start with -- have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a step-by-step answer for your question.

[image]

First I draw the lines with `\draw` and define the angle after `--++`, then I add the questionmark at half the length of the arrow with `pos=0.5` and then I add the other labels unsing the node commands. You can play around with the positioning like `above, below, left, rigth` and their combinations.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (0:2) node[pos=0.5, above] {?} node[below] {$x+l_1 \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (45:2) node[pos=0.5, above] {?} node[right] {$x+(l_1-l_2) \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (90:2) node[pos=0.5, left] {?} node[above right] {$x+l_2 \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (135:2) node[pos=0.5, left] {?} node[left] {$x+(-l_1+l_2) \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (180:2) node[pos=0.5, below] {?} node[below] {$x-l_1 \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (225:2) node[pos=0.5, below] {?} node[left] {$x+(-l_1-l_2) \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) --++ (270:2) node[pos=0.5, right] {?} node[below left] {$x-l_2 \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0) node[fill=white, opacity=0.5, below right] {x} --++ (315:2) node[pos=0.5, above] {?} node[right] {$x+(l_1-l_2) \cdot h$} node[fill=black, circle, scale=0.25] {};
        
        \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$h \cdot z^n$};
        \draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\N}
        
        \tikzset{structureline/.style={<->,black,thin}}
        
        \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\N}
        \foreach\j in{text}{
            \draw[structureline] (0,0) -- (\i*\angle:4)node[label=\i*\angle:\j]{};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```